# Windowing Functions

Tags: postgresql

I have the following events table.

```
key time_stamp  geohash
k1  1           thred0y
k2  5           thred0v
k4  7           thre6rd
k3  9           thre6rg
k1  10          thred3t
k1  12          thred3u
k2  14          thred3s
```

Where I want to cluster the keys into groups if they fall with in 500mts range in 10 minutes of time interval.

I tried cross join them and

```
select a.key, b.key, a.geohash, b.geohash, a.time_stamp, b.time_stamp,
  round(ST_Distance(ST_PointFromGeoHash(a.geohash, 4326), ST_PointFromGeoHash(b.geohash, 4326), true)) distance,
  abs(round(extract(EPOCH from a.time_stamp - b.time_stamp)/60))
from t a, t b
where a.key <> b.key
  and a.time_stamp between b.time_stamp - interval '10 min' and b.time_stamp + interval '10 min'
  and ST_Distance(ST_PointFromGeoHash(a.geohash, 4326), ST_PointFromGeoHash(b.v, 4326), true) <= 500
  and least(a.key, b.key) = a.key
order by a.time_stamp desc
```

However the query works good with small data and additionally the query only works if there are two distinct keys but not more than 2.

Any inputs on how to proceed further will be helpful.

I added some sample data for test, https://pastebin.com/iVD1WU4Y.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by clustering keys within 60 minutes along with 1.2 km apart.

```
with x as (
select key, time_stamp, geo, prev_ts, geo_hash6,
 count(case when prev_ts is null or prev_ts > 60 then 1 else null end) over(order by time_stamp) cluster_id
from (
    select key, time_stamp, geo,  
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_stamp - lag(time_stamp) over(order by time_stamp)) prev_ts,
        substring(geo, 1, 6) geo_hash6
    from t
) a
order by cluster_id, geo_hash6, geo, time_stamp)
select x.cluster_id, x.key, x.geo_hash6, min(time_stamp) first_time, max(time_stamp) last_time
from x, (select cluster_id, geo_hash6, count(distinct key) num_uniques from x group by cluster_id, geo_hash6) y
where x.cluster_id = y.cluster_id and x.geo_hash6 = y.geo_hash6 and y.num_uniques > 2
group by x.cluster_id, x.geo_hash6, x.key
order by x.cluster_id, x.geo_hash6;
```

Any suggestions improving the solution is welcome.